# CKEditor: assign shortcuts to custom defined styles

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ckeditor

I'd like to assign keyboard shortcuts to custom defined styles, for instance having defined:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'custom_styles',
    [
        // Block-level styles
        { name : 'Title', element : 'h1' },
        { name : 'Summary' , element : 'p' },

    ]);
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet = 'custom_styles';
```

how do I assign a keyboard shortcut to 'Title' and 'Summary' ?